# Printing lines between two patterns while getting one pattern from another file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a problem to solve but I' am unable to do it myself.

File 1 containing ID's and looks like:

```
>AIM49244.1
>NP_722551.1
>YP_002790883.1
>AGS41451.1
>AIM49245.1
>BAM74427.1
>CCC55433.1
```

File 2 looks like:

```
>AIM49244.1 polyprotein [Aedes flavivirus]
(several lines of text only Alphabetic)
>NZ_03930.3 polyprotein [please help]
(several lines of text only Alphabetic)
>NP_722551.1 polyprotein [Alkhumra hemorrhagic fever virus]
(several lines of text only Alphabetic)
>NP_123456.7 polyprotein [Foo bar Foo bar]
several lines of text
and so on
```

With the ID's from file 1 I want to extract the headline containing the ID and the following lines of text in file 2 until the next ID begins.

Example result for the output File:

```
>AIM49244.1 polyprotein [Aedes flavivirus]
(several lines of text only Alphabetic)
>NP_722551.1 polyprotein [Alkhumra hemorrhagic fever virus]
(several lines of text only Alphabetic)
```

I have a solution but it works only if in File 2 the description line (starting with >) is only followed by one line.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$1; next}$1 in A{print $0, getline; print $0}' File_1 File_2
```

But I' am not able to adept it to the new problem. I tried to get it to work with range patterns but it is not working properly. So it would be very nice if you could help me :)

Comment: This looks like fasta files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `getline` unless you have a VERY specific need and fully understand all of the implications and caveats. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

In this case all you need is:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { ids[$1]; next }
/^>/ { inTargetBlock = ($1 in ids ? 1 : 0) }
inTargetBlock
' file1 file2
```

Comment: Can't just `inTargetBlock = $1 in ids`

Comment: IMHO that's much less clear and so not worth saving the couple of characters for.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. As for getline I know it can do a lot but it worked for me in that way. But if I find time I will have a look at all its functions.

Comment: You're welcome but I think you misunderstood my point - I'm not suggesting you use getline more, I'm saying use it less (almost never).

Comment: I have a question regarding your answer. Sorry that it comes now but on Friday I was a bit in a hurry. I don't really understand how your code is able to print out the lines of text after a >(header). 
`NR==FNR { ids[$1]; next }` is getting all the ID's from the first file into an array
`/^>/ { inTargetBlock = ($1 in ids ? 1 : 0) }
inTargetBlock` is searching for a line that starts with > and then inTargetBlock is set to 1 or 0 depending if the line is in the ids array or not. If it is inTargetBlock is set to one which results in printing of the line. But how is the following text printed?

Comment: Setting it to 1 doesn't print the line, testing if its value is non-zero prints the line. A true condition invokes the default action of printing the current record. `inTargetBlock` on it's oen line is shorthand for `inTargetBlock { print $0 }`.